# How to start VMware Virtual Network Editor from command line

Tags: vmware

I've just installed VMWare Workstation 9 on a headless Ubuntu 12.04 server. How can I run the Virtual Network Editor from the command line? When attempting to run it via the vmware program over X (Edit > Virtual Network Editor), nothing happens - thus I am looking for how to start it stand-alone.

What is the command to run it alone?

Comment: Just a suggestion try proxmox http://askubuntu.com/questions/243342/is-there-an-open-source-alternative-to-vmware-vsphere-server-like-a-ubuntu-or-s/292115#292115

Comment: Can you add your own answer to the question (in the answer section below, click "answer your own question") :)

Comment: @Seth Added as answer. I had to wait 8 hours or so because I am a newb :).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer. In the default Workstation install, the network editor was located at:

```
/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-netcfg
```

I had to run the above as root, and the editor opened in an X window.

Comment: or just vmware-netcfg