# How Do I Restrict VMWare Workstation to Use Only Eth1 directly?

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-workstation

My machine has two ethernet ports.  I want to make VMWare exclusively use Eth1.

I have a fresh install of Xubuntu Core 15.10 (amd64). I installed VMWare Workstation 12.  It would not run, until I did [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689123/vmware-wont-work-after-ubuntu-upgrade).

The VMWare virutal network editor will not run from the Workstation menu.  When I go to terminal and [run vmware-netcfg as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293339/how-to-start-vmware-virtual-network-editor-from-command-line/294243#294243), it dies without error.

Can I manually do this in the Xubuntu Network Connections application?  Any other ideas?

Comment: After reading Thomas W's answer, I realized my question is worded wrong.  I don't want to prohibit Eth1 being used by anything else.  I want my virtual machines to use only eth1.  Don't I need to set up vmnet2 to do that?

Comment: I would prefer my router to do DNS, NAT, etc. instead of my PC.

Comment: I did find this suggestion for vmware 6, but the storage locations are differnt from vmware 12.  http://forum.linuxcareer.com/threads/1648-Changing-vmware-vmnet-bridged-physical-network-interface

Comment: Just so anyone who has the same problem will know...  I tried sudo, pkexec and sudo su to run both usr/bin/vmware-netcfg and usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-netcfg which I found with catfish.

Comment: I edited this shell script file in usr/bin/vmwre-netcfg and added export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1, but that did not change the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> This answer addresses the new question by the OP, in comments:
>
> > After reading Thomas W's answer, I realized my question is worded wrong. I don't want to prohibit Eth1 being used by anything else. I want my virtual machines to use only eth1. Don't I need to set up vmnet2 to do that?
> >     I would prefer my router to do DNS, NAT, etc. instead of my PC.

You would need the VMware Virtual Network editor tool, run with sudo, to make changes, and then restart the VMware service.

But essentially, you have to edit `vmnet0` in the editor, and instruct it which network interface to be 'bridged' to.  That will allow the VM to 'work' over the ethernet interface as if it were connected to the network directly.  Note that this does not always work with all network interfaces and setups, and if this does not work correctly then you will need to use NAT or use an external ethernet adapter.

---

**UPDATE** - November 11, 2015.

In VMware Workstation 12, the networking configuration which addresses the bridged network is in `/etc/vmware/networking`.

Look for `add_bridge_mapping` lines.  For all your physical interfaces, you may have multiple of these lines, like seen here:

```
add_bridge_mapping eth1 -1
add_bridge_mapping wlan0 -1
add_bridge_mapping eth0 0
```

Change these so that the one you *want* to have the bridged connection to has the 0, and the others have -1.  I would emulate this format, with -1 being ahead of the 0 lines.

Untested, but this is really the changes that the Virtual Network Editor does.

Comment: which brings me back to the reason for my post... I cannot get it to run.

Comment: @NJRandy I'm digging into my `vmnet0` configs on my system and will provide a CLI way to edit... but no guarantees it'll work 100%

Comment: In network settings, vwmare created by default:  vmnet1 and vmnet8.  vmnet1 has a generated MAC address, and a fixed IP address of 172.16.227.1, netmask 255.255.255.0, gateway 0.0.0.0.  MTU is set to automatic.  All users  may access is ticked. Neither 802.1x nor dcb nor IP6 is enabled. vmnet8 has exactly the same settings, but the IP is 192.168.46.1.

Comment: @NJRandy The specifics of each aren't relevant, nor is IPv6 (I don't think it's supported in VMware virtual networking).  I'm still hunting manual modification though...

Comment: Contents of that file: VERSION=1,0
answer VNET_1_DHCP yes
answer VNET_1_DHCP_CFG_HASH 0AFA20BCAA2E41DD7AE3F6B6E0E0BD6B04F0B047
answer VNET_1_HOSTONLY_NETMASK 255.255.255.0
answer VNET_1_HOSTONLY_SUBNET 172.16.227.0
answer VNET_1_VIRTUAL_ADAPTER yes
answer VNET_8_DHCP yes
answer VNET_8_DHCP_CFG_HASH 0576041D769AC244FC9934E0FCFD90D9EC86DC1C
answer VNET_8_HOSTONLY_NETMASK 255.255.255.0
answer VNET_8_HOSTONLY_SUBNET 192.168.46.0
answer VNET_8_NAT yes
answer VNET_8_VIRTUAL_ADAPTER yes